# How can check if data is inserted or not in crate db using python?

Tags: python-3.x, crate, cratedb

I am trying to insert data in crate DB using the crate client python package. I am not able to check if data is inserted in crate db or not? if one record is inserted in one table and another record has not been inserted into another table. How can I rollback first table data in crate DB

Comment: Are you looking for `transactions` in CrateDB. As of now, CrateDB does not support transactions

Comment: yes, But I want to confirm if the data is inserted or not? How can I check that? Please let me know if you have any solution. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: the only way I can think of right now is check other table after the process and if the values are not present in the second table, delete the value you have inserted in the first table.  You can create a wrapper over the existing library that can work for you. Think in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

Are you having problem with making sure that data is inserted in db or something else?

You can do something like this:

```
result = cursor.executemany(query:str, items:list)
```

and result will be the list of dicts for every item you've tried to insert

```
[{'rowcount': 1}, {'rowcount': 1}]
```

if something went wrong rowcount would be -2 and you'll get error message.
Otherwise you can just query the db and see if that item is inserted previously.